# Cannot Connect to Hidden Wi-Fi Network

Tags: wireless, 16.04

Since upgrading to 16.04 LTS, I cannot manually connect to a saved network.

I can connect if the network is not hidden after a rescan - just selecting the network from the menu or waiting for it to connect automatically. I can also connect if I type in the details manually. However if I select a saved network the Connect button on the dialog is greyed out.

I have tried saving a new version of the network but have the same problem. I've also tried storing the password for just the current user and for all users but both have the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its a known bug, already reported
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/1542733

Answer (score 2):

As a workaround, if the network is not actually hidden, you can force a scan by running

```
sudo iwlist wlan0 scan
```

where `wlan0` is the name of your wireless interface.

Comment: Yes, I ended up putting this in my root crontab :-(

Answer (score 0):

To (possibly) add more to this problem, I just did a clean-install to an IBM Thinkpad of Ubuntu 16.04LTS, and all went well until the install finished. The Router is a hidden SSID, and could NOT connect. Having control of the Router, I made the SSID visible, and after Thinkpad reboot, was able to connect. During the session, I reset the Router to Hidden SSID, the Thinkpad was able to keep connection to the SSID until it was rebooted. On reboot, it could no longer connect to the hidden SSID. It is clearly an issue of not being able to negotiate a hidden SSID.  From the various problems reported on several bug submissions, it is obvious that there is more than one connectivity issue that is buggy still in 16.04LTS.